# Providing remote desktops via VNC

Tags: virtual-desktop

We have to provide 100 users a remote desktop with access to a browser.  Firefox works fine.  The thought is to deploy a remote desktop via desktop virtualization, so each user can get a customized desktop that they can then manage.  The thought is to also deliver Linux desktops, since all that is needed is the browser.

1. Does anyone have any experience with Red Hat's desktop virtualization?
2. Citrix solutions?
3. What would the tradeoffs be if we attempted to do this using Red Hat desktops via VNC?  How would this scale?

Comment: We would need *way* more information to judge on that...also, shopping recommendations are off-topic here. But you (most likely) don't want VNC if your users should work with Firefox, you want thin-clients or stripped-down workstations.

Comment: VNC is a bad decision for that purpose. Use a Linux server and use XServer (start Firefox on the remote server and export the display to the local machine) or you can use ["NX NoMachine"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Sorry - n00b on the site, so didn't want to drive the conversation to off-topic areas.

Comment: Ok - so, no VNC. With thin clients, we will need something that is 'turnkey', in the sense that users will not be tech savvy to export displays.  What would a good place be to get vendor comparisons? There are so many solutions available, including Desktop and App virtualization solutions.